React 18 - tsconfig.json cannot write file 'vite.config.js because it would overwrite input file.ts
I just create React 18 project using JavaScript but when I open the App.jsx gives me error like this

After I added tsconfig.json, the first line on tsconfig.json gives me error

Is there a way to tackle the error on tsconfig.json?

How exactly did you create your project? Since you appear to be trying to use Vite and Typescript, you should have simply generated the project using npm create vite@latest react-counter -- --template react-ts. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project

@Phil I created new project with npm create vite@latest react-counter -- --template react . And when I open App.jsx it keeps giving me error about 'React' refers to a UMD global,

What is "it"? Can you share a screenshot of the error for context?

@Phil screenshot just added

Seems like it's probably just a temporary VS Code issue. Try this suggestion

@Phil I already tried that, nothing changed. And if I delete tsconfig.json the errors on JSX files came back
